# Hotel won't honor last year's promotional price because I've rescheduled my stay

Tags: bookings

I booked a hotel at a discounted price of $1200 due to an "end of year promotion" that said if I booked before 2023 I would get a cheaper price. I did not want any of the inclusions that came with the room, so I agreed to pay the full amount instead of a deposit.

Now that it is the new year, I need to change my dates to later in the year, which is allowed if I notify them 30 days in advance. However, they will not honor the promotional price I tried to secure and will be charging me the new rates for my stay.

I feel like I am being taken advantage of; do I have any legal grounds here?

Comment: "I feel like I am being taken advantage of". Reading your question makes me feel the complete opposite. You try to take advantage of the hotel

Comment: Promototional bookings are often for a specific time period. You're not paying a discounted price for " X days of stay", you're paying a discounted price for "X days of stay between Date A and Date B". If you want to schedule it for outside that range, it's no surprise you won't get the discount.

Comment: The point of their sale was to get some 4th quarter numbers bumped. You rescheduling undoes that. They don't owe you sale pricing outside of the sale terms.

Comment: @Natasha A Was the promotion for a certain period, or just any time in 2023?

Answer (score 35):

The answer will depend on the specific T&Cs of the promotional rates you booked, but generally speaking, **no, you don't.**

The hotel gave you a discount for specific dates, but you are not staying on those dates, so the hotel has no obligation to offer any discounts on different dates.  If anything, many of these "100% prepayment" deals are *completely* inflexible, so you're lucky they're allowing you to use the money as credit for a different stay.

For what it's worth, stay dates for promotions are often limited to specific periods, so it's quite possible that you would not have been able to get the discounted rates for your new dates even if you had booked earlier.

Comment: "The hotel gave you a discount for specific dates" Did they? Or did they give it for securing business as early as possible? (I agree that you shouldn't  expect to get the discount if you reschedule in 2023 though)

Comment: @Reznik Usually it's per specific dates.

Comment: @Azor Ahai -him It's not clear from the question, but it could very well be a certain percentage discount for any date, with prices of course varying through the seasons. In that case, the hotel of course still has no obligation to give the discount, but in early January it wouldn't seem strange to me to still do this as a courtesy. That would also make most answers and comments here a bit too harsh in my opinion...

Comment: @Reznik I've never seen a discount structured like that. You do get X% off "Best Available Rate" sometimes, but typically the base rate is some absurd maximum price far higher than actual rates, making the discount useless in practice.

Comment: @lambshaanxy I did get a discount like that once, therefore I was surprised by the reactions to this question. But I'm not a very experienced traveller, so I'll just let the experts sort this one out.

Answer (score 6):

> I feel like I am being taken advantage of;

Did you read the terms and conditions of the promotional booking before you committed to it?  Most likely, the hotel is abiding by those terms and conditions, in which case the best way to avoid feeling taken advantage of is to read them when you commit.  I know this sounds flippant, but I mean it in earnest, and I am speaking from experience.  The negative emotional impact of this situation would have been far smaller if you'd informed yourself from the start.

Of course, it's also possible that the hotel isn't following the terms and conditions.  In that case...

> do I have any legal grounds here?

The best way to know what grounds you have or do not have is to read the terms and conditions.

There is one other very important point to keep in mind, however.  *Not everything in the terms and conditions is necessarily legal.*  Consumer protection law often places restrictions on consumer contracts; any term of the contract that violates one of these restrictions is typically null and void.  This varies widely from one jurisdiction to the next, and it can be time consuming to research, but if there is a consumer advocacy organization in the hotel's city you might want to run the story by them to get their take on it.

Furthermore, if the company told you verbally something that was more favorable than what was written in the contract, the more favorable term could actually be a part of your contract, though it will be difficult to prove in court what they said.  My approach in these cases is to argue to a customer service manager that the company has a duty to train its employees properly, that it didn't fulfill that duty, and that it should honor the promise even if the written contract says otherwise.

Answer (score 3):

It heavily depends on the exact terms and conditions given to you.

But I find it rather unlikely that you were provided with a "as long as you tell us 30 days in advance you can reshedule to any other date for the same price" clause. More likely you have "30 days notice to cancel or reshedule" clause, which **does** include the option for the hotel to charge you for any price differences.

Let me give you two examples:

1. You book the hotel for dates in the off-season but reshedule to a date at the peak (where prices are easily 2x to 3x higher).
2. You book the hotel for the high-discount and reshedule your room to someday in the future (as long as do so 30 days in advance)?

Both things would ruin a hotel if they allowed their guest to do that.

Your best option is either to honor the booking as you made it, or ask for a refund.

Answer (score 2):

When you booked that room the first time, for the promotional price, you booked that date and THAT was a booking. Fast forward to your modifications being made, you've now made a NEW booking. Technically. The person working the front desk is probably just using the system they have in front of them and doesn't plan on getting in trouble just to make you happy. I recommend scheduling a conversation with the manager of the hotel and discussing it with them. Hotel managers have a lot of control over the price of a room. But they will not budge if you come at them sideways. If they refuse to help ask them for the contact information for their boss. Etc. But just stay polite about it all along the way and you have a pretty good chance of success.

Comment: I echo the "stay polite".  I have a good success rate for complaints.  I am persistent but polite.  Shouting, swearing, or other bad behaviour gives them an excuse to stop discussing.